# Any method to modify 'Page Information' slug in InDesign Output to PDF?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, metadata

I'd like to try to include the filename of any linked .csv file in the data that is output by checking "*Page Information*" section under Marks and Bleeds when exporting to PDF in InDesign CC 2018.

(The solution needs to be a relatively simple process that is easily adapted on other workstations by other users in my department)

I'm trying to determine if there's an option to keep everything that's already present in the PDF's *page info* but to also include the name of any linked files - particularly linked .csv's.

I'd like to avoid creating a custom slug from scratch if at all possible.

Comment: Embedded files are separate from the document itself, so no (at least I don’t think so, not without a fair bit of scripting). You _can_ get this info on an individual page in the document by using captions, but it’ll be there in the document itself, not added on-the-fly when exporting to PDF.

Comment: You won't be able to change the UI behavior (checking Page information can't trigger anything else than it's supposed to do). But... you can probably retrieve links name and place them in a frame. Anyhow, a script will definitely be needed.